# Create new android material datepicker on fragmentdialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

Hello guys on my application I was using the material theme v 1.0.0 now I have switched to the version 1.2.0 and I have seen that there is a new datepicker.

I am trying to modify my fragment dialog using the new datepicker but without success.

This is my current code in `onCreateDialog()` in `public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragmentimplements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`:

```
DatePickerDialog dialogDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),this, year - 40, month, day);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
c.set(1861, 2, 17);
dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
dialogDatePicker.getDatePicker().getTouchables().get( 0 ).performClick(); //show year before date
return dialogDatePicker;
```

with this code I get this dialog:

[image]

But now I would like to get this new datepicker always starting from the selection of the year:
[image]

I saw that it refers to MaterialDatePicker.Builder but I can't integrate it into the DialogFragment oncreate.
Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I don't think you need a DatePickerFragment.The MaterialDatePicker is a DialogFragment

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with the old version I have used DialogFragment to customize some aspects such as to block the rotation when the datepicker is open. How can I customize these aspects using MaterialDatePicker directly?

Comment: Not so simple. The onCreateDialog is final and you can't extend it.

Comment: In the old version of the datapicker it was not final and I had used onStop, onResume and onPause to control the rotation of the screen. Unfortunately if you rotate the screen with the datapicker open it appears differently than when you open it with the screen already rotated.

So there is no way to be able to use the new version of the datapicker having the freedom to control the rotation and to directly open the visualization of the year when the datapicker opens?